# Reduce price by 10% using a trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger where the price entered in the Price column of Courses table would automatically be reduced by 10% after entry. I'm brand new to triggers and am creating my first one; I'm not sure if MySQL lets you declare empty variables which is what I'm assuming I'll need to subtract it by the original value entered

```
Delimiter #
CREATE TRIGGER course_discount_table
BEFORE UPDATE ON Courses 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET New.Price = (New 0.10 * Price)
SET Price = (Price - Price)
END #
DELIMITER ;
```

Of course, the code is a total mess but would really appreciate any help

Comment: Defining business logic in DB triggers is a weird idea. No backend language available?

Comment: Using a trigger for this purpose is not a good idea, you're obfuscating important logic that should be part of the application or at worst in a stored procedure where the logic is clearly visible and documented.

Comment: I see, thanks guys. I'll come up with another idea for my trigger then. Appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following would every time you update a course take effect and the proce reduced.

Better would be to have a column, that control that behaviour, or a  lowest price that would not be underwhelmed.

```
Delimiter #
CREATE TRIGGER course_discount_table
BEFORE UPDATE ON Courses 
FOR EACH ROW 
   SET New.Price = NEW.Price - ( 0.10 * NEW.Price);
END #
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several tips:

- If you have an `END`, you must also have a `BEGIN`.
- If your trigger body were only one statement, you don't need a `BEGIN...END` block, and in that case you wouldn't need to change the `DELIMITER`.
- Every time you reference a column of the new row, prefix it with `NEW.`.
- Each statement in a block must end with a semicolon.
- I have no idea what `SET PRICE = (Price - Price)` is even supposed to do! :-)
- Changing the price in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger means it will continue to reduce by 10% after *every* UPDATE. So if you change the title or the time or whatever, it'll keep reducing until it's zero.

  It would be better, in my opinion, to record the original price, then
  add a generated column to show the discounted price. This you can do without a trigger.

Demo:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Courses (
    ->   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   name TEXT NOT NULL,
    ->   original_price NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL,
    ->   discounted_price NUMERIC(9,2) AS (original_price * 0.90)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into Courses set name = 'Math', original_price = 100;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Courses;
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
| id | name | original_price | discounted_price |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | Math |         100.00 |            90.00 |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: he seems to want to reduce the price all times the row is updated

Comment: Why would anyone want that?

Comment: When he changes the course time again again, because no one wants to book it, the price could sink by 10 procent in hope hat someone still book it.

Comment: But using a trigger, it would reduce the price after _any_ update, even if they only need to fix a typo in the course title.

Comment: Very helpful Bill, thank you. And yes, I wanted to reduce the cost of any course prices added in the future so I changed it to BEFORE INSERT.